# Cambio de icono al inicio de sesion Angular

Tags: angular

cuando se inicie sesion me cambie el icono a la foto de perfil esto solo funciona hasta que le doy f5 para actualizar mientras me lo mantiene en blanco lo estoy haciendo a travez de un ngDoCheck cuando cambia el estado del localstorage me ingresa pero no funciona bien y me manda estos errores en consola alguna idea de como arreglarlo

```
ngDoCheck() {
this.checkStatus = this.localStorageItem();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias mostrar la parte de tu HTML donde usas 'role'?

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error te lo está diciendo:

> No se puede leer 'rol' de `null`

La siguiente línea te dice que el error está en `HeaderComponent.html` en la línea 18.

Esto normalmente significa que estás usando una propiedad de una variable que no se ha inicializado (por lo tanto es `null`).

Digamos que tenés una variable `user` que contiene una propiedad `role`.
Tenés dos opciones:

### 1) Usar  ["Angular safe navigation operator"](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) ("?")

> Con el operador de navegación segura (?) Angular deja de evaluar expresiones cuando encuentre el primer valor `null` y muestra el componente sin errores.

Por lo que podrías hacer algo como:

```
<div>{{user?.role}}</div>
```

### 2) Inicializar la variable antes de mostrar la vista

Para que Angular no se encuentre con una variable `null` en el HTML. También podés asegurarte que `user` tenga un valor:

```
   user = {} // O algún valor por mientras. La idea es que no sea ni null ni undefined;
   constructor() {
      // ...
   }
```

---

A veces la mejor idea es usar el operador de seguridad. Pues te permite más flexibilidad. `{{user?.names?.first}}` es totalmente válido.